# Time Fixed Effects for Cross-Sectional Data

Tags: least-squares, econometrics

Hi StackExchange Community,
I have been browsing around but couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I have a dataset with funds that were launched in the last 40 years and the final performance that they achieved until they were liquidated. This means I have their latest performance as of today (most were liquidated anyway, the others will be ignored), which means 1 measure per fund. I am going to analyze the performance persistence of the fund managers responsible for the funds.

From what I see this is a cross-sectional dataset (only 1 performance measurement per fund) but with funds that were started in different years. As I am only going to analyze US funds (no industry differentiation) I don't think I would need Entity fixed effects/dummies for the fund managers or location. I would still need Year fixed effects/dummies though because they were running over different periods of time and I would therefore like to differentiate by launch year.

My problem is:

- Am I right about this being cross-sectional data or is this an unbalanced panel?
- Would applying the year dummy make this a fixed effects model?
- As the fixed effects model seems to be usually applied to panel data it seems there is not a possibility to just run yearly fixed effects but also entity fixed effects are needed.

I found something on another thread:

> "The unobserved effects model is modeled as: =+ where
>   =++ .  A one-way error model assumes =0 while a
>   two-way error allows for ∈ℝ"

If the one-way model only considers entity effects it wouldn't be applicable as I don't need entity differentiation. Is there a way of having a one-way model that only considers Year Fixed Effects/Dummies, without applying any fixed entity effects?

Thanks in advance.